# After flushing, toilet bowl fills before tank fills

Tags: toilet

After flushing, the bowl on the toilet fills too high, nearly to the top before the tank does.
I do not know what to try first.

Answer (score 4):

You have a partial drain blockage, probably in the S shaped toilet trap.

1. Wait.  The things that go down toilets should disintegrate quickly in water.  Sometimes they disintegrate slowly.  People who are highly constipated or who use facial tissues instead of toilet paper can cause this.  Sometimes waiting solves the problem.   Other things don't disintegrate at all ... rags, sponges, tampons, etc ... then go on to #2.
2. Try a *good *plunger.

[image: plunger]

3. Try a toilet snake

[image: toilet plunger]

4. If those don't work, you have to remove the toilet from the floor an examine the trap.  Look on youtube how to remove and replace a toilet or call a plumber if you're not comfortable with it, or if it is your only toilet.

[image: toilet trap]

Comment: [It's a trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admiral_Ackbar#%22It's_a_trap!%22) But seriously, this is the right answer, because if the trap/etc. was all totally clear then when the toilet got even a little over the "normal" level it would drain (to the normal level, not an actual flush) automatically.

Comment: I would never buy a toilet with that weird of a trap.   Seems like a logjam waiting to happen!

Comment: That's just a random picture I found that already had "The Trap" written on it.  I'm not suggesting that you, OP, or anyone does or should have a trap in this shape or in any particular shape.  Disclaimer over.  :)

Comment: @jay613 - that would really be a trap.   Also what do you think makes a good plunger?    Honestly.   I have seen some plungers work great for some toilets and some for others.

Comment: @dmoore A good plunger is not too soft and not too hard and conforms nicely to the shape of your toilet bowl.  I find that a fairly thick rubber one with a neck like in my picture often works nicely, better than vinyl, plastic, or bell shaped ones.   The ones that come packaged in pretty ceramic or metal holders from home decor outlets are usually crap.  The ones in supermarkets and dollar stores are usually crap.

Answer (score 1):

Muriatic acid is a choice if a plunger doesn't work.   I am not a fan of the toilet snake because sometimes it pushes the clog worse, and if you use enough force you can crack things and find out later.

Muriatic acid is some serious stuff.   You need to be wearing gloves and eyewear and a mask but it is easy and quick.   If the toilet is "full" you can just pour a cup of the acid directly in the toilet - don't splash it.   As the water settles, flush.   If it still won't go down keep adding a cup each time.   Never had a toilet go past 3 tries and most in 1.   Also the acid will make cleaning the toilet easier.